# install additional packages in vagrant box configured in puphpet

Tags: debian, vagrant, puphpet

I wan to know if for installing something like vim I have to run the command 
`apt-get install vim` or should I change my puphpet `config.yaml` to do this and then do a `vagrant up` will the later start the whole process of downloading and installation all over again?

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* manually install anything within your Puppet-managed VM. Use the `config.yaml`! Simply add the required package to the server.packages array and then run `$ vagrant provision`.

Comment: I don't know if i should make this another question but I am using git bash to ssh to the vm to browse files and stuff am I supposed to use that? or should I use something else?. Can I execute all the commands from git bash?  Thanks